# Android error when import csv

Tags: android, sqlite, import-from-csv

I'm trying to import all the data from the CSV file and overwrite those in the table in SQLite database. I have this method but I get error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String`

---

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File exportDir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath());
    File csvFile = new File(exportDir,"myfile.csv");
 try {
         deleteTable();
   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  CSVReader dataRead = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
   String[] vv = null;
   while((vv = dataRead.readNext())!=null) {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
     String strDate = sdf.format( vv[0] );
            cv.clear();
     cv.put(Table.DATA,strDate);
     cv.put(Table.A,vv[1]);
     cv.put(Table.B,vv[2]);
     cv.put(Table.C,vv[3]);
     cv.put(Table.D,vv[4]);
     SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      db.insert(MyTable.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);

   }
   dataRead.close();

} catch (Exception e) {

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String strDate = sdf.format( vv[0] );
```

You can't use `SimpleDateFormat.format()` to format a `String`.

Use `format()` for converting `Date` objects to `String`s. Use `parse()` to convert `String`s to `Date` objects.